# Date time library for gwt

Tags: gwt, jodatime

I am working on a gwt application which involves advanced manipulations with date times: convert from one timezone to another, etc. Gwt has some low level stuff for working with dates but they are too low level for me. Are there any options similar to joda time or threeten for gwt?

Comment: did you end up using joda time in your gwt app?

Comment: @Justin Actually, I wrote my own library tailored to my specific needs :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at the following options.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-time/

http://code.google.com/p/goda-time/

http://github.com/mping/gwt-joda-time

Comment: They are all obsolete and not maintained.

Comment: yes. sadly these seems to be the only options right now. I read that gwt-time is pretty useful on gwt issue list http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=603#c63

Comment: This answer its pretty oudated, for Date operations you can use GWT Calendarutil: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html

Answer (score 1):

This is my DateTimeUtil class

```
public class DateTimeUtil {
    public static String getYear(Date date) {
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy").format(date);
    }
    public static String getMonth(Date date) {
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM").format(date);
    }
    public static String getDay(Date date) {
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd").format(date);
    }
    public static String getHour(Date date) {
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH").format(date);
    }
    public static String getMinute(Date date) {
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("mm").format(date);
    }
    public static String getSecond(Date date) {
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("ss").format(date);
    }

    // The String year must to have yyyy format

    public static Date getDate(String years, String months, String days, String hours, String minutes, String seconds) {
        DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = dtf.parse(years + "-" + months + "-" + days + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        GWT.log("date parsed " + date);
        return date;
    }
}
```