# Building a date from year, month and day in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I need to build a `Date` from year, month and day in GWT. How can I do that without the use of `Calendar`, as it is not available in GWT?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311754/date-time-library-for-gwt

Answer (score 3):

You can use `java.util.Date`

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setYear(year);   // setting year
date.setMonth(month); // setting month
date.setDate(date);   // setting day of month
```

If you don't want to have any other fields:

```
date.setHours(0);   // setting hours to 0
date.setMinutes(0); // setting minutes to 0
date.setSeconds(0); // setting seconds to 0
```

This way your code can still have milliseconds, however you could easily get rid of it:

```
long time = date.getTime();    // getting timestamp
time = (time / 1000L) * 1000L; // getting rid of milliseconds by integer division
                               // or alternatively
time -= time % 1000L;          // getting rid of milliseconds by substracting remainder
date.setTime(time);            // setting the timestamp without milliseconds
```

You could use the second method to get rid of hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds too, but it wouldn't be precise because of the leap seconds.

Note: these methods (except `getTime()` and `setTime()`) are deprecated, but this may be the most straightforward way to do this in GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTimeFormat` that provide **Internationalization** also.

```
    DateTimeFormat format=DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date=format.parse("03/11/2014");
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

```
Mon Nov 03 00:00:00 IST 2014
```

For more info read about [GWT DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html).