# How can i extract hours & minutes from a timestamp in GWT?

Tags: date, gwt, calendar, timestamp

At first i tried this with the Calender-Class but then i read, that it is not supported by GWT. Do you have suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Date startDate = reservation.getStartDate();` getStartDate returns a timestamp

Comment: `startHour.setValue(Integer.toString(startDate.getHours()));`

Comment: It is working, but getHours is deprecated... any suggestions? (i am working with GWT)

Answer (score 2):

Since GWT 2.7 you can use [JsDate](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/core/client/JsDate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use the deprecated `Date` API. You should probably create a utility class for such date manipulation, something like [`CalendarUtil`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html), but for hours/minutes. If `Calendar` (or any alternative) is every ported to GWT (or a date time library surfaces [that is actually maintained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10311754/181497)), you can change the implementation in your utility class and the rest of your application will remain the same.