# GWT Time on Client: What's the 2015 way to go?

Tags: gwt, time

Now that `java.util.Date` is almost entirely deprecated and GWT does not emulate the new util `java.util.Calendar` I am not sure if it's a big fun to work with time on the GWT client side.

I know that there are "[*options*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311754/date-time-library-for-gwt)" but those were not maintained over years. Also the GWT `CalendarUtil` is entirely relying on `java.util.Date` and therefore has to be enjoyed with care.

So what should I use on the client side for time handling in GWT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until we have Java 8 and `java.time`, the way to go is still `java.util.Date`, with appropriate `@SuppressWarnings`. Either that or dealing with numeric timestamps or GWT's `JsDate`, or possibly wrapping some JS libs.

JS itself is quite limited when it comes to date time handling, hence GWT's limitations too.

Comment: Okay, I see! If I may ask: Do you know if the GWT [`CalendarUtil`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html) is going to stay the way it is and just its implementation is going to change? I am asking because `CalendarUtil` itself is not `@deprecated` but the `java.util.Date` it's currently using is. Am I assuming right that you guys are just going to change its implementation but not the interface?

Comment: `CalendarUtil` is very likely to stay the same, and not even be updated to `java.time`, even internally.