# How to calculate next week?

Tags: java, time

I want to precisely calculate the time one week from a given date, but the output I get back is one hour early.


code:

```
long DURATION = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
System.out.println("    now: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
System.out.println("next week: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + DURATION));
```

output:

```
now: Wed Sep 16 09:52:36 IRDT 2015
next week: Wed Sep 23 08:52:36 IRST 2015
```

How can I calculate this correctly?

Comment: Use Java 8's Time API, use JodaTime, use `Calendar` for the love of sanity, but DON'T try and use millisecond arithmetic

Comment: @MadProgrammer actually, if you don't use Joda Time yet, nowadays you're better off using threetenbp instead

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer. Using `JodaTime` would make this really simple. Joda provides methods like `plusWeek()` where you can add weeks to a given date

Comment: @fge I'd say that's a matter of needs and requirements, I can see where the value might be in using 3-10bp to make the code more "compatible", but it still lacks some of the nice functionality in JodaTime, which might make appearances in later releases

Comment: @MadProgrammer, i want to use the code in GWT, and can't use Java 8 or other third parties, please suggest me another workaround

Comment: `Calendar`?  It's part of the core API since 1.1

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Class 'java.util.Calendar' is not present in JRE Emulation Library so it cannot be used in client code of GWT.

Comment: Not sure if will help [CalendarUtil](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html) or maybe [Date time library for gwt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311754/date-time-library-for-gwt)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Thanks, i use  Date now = new Date();   CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(now, 7); and worked precisely.

Comment: Your original program works correctly. The difference between "Wed Sep 16 09:52:36 IRDT 2015" and "Wed Sep 23 08:52:36 IRST 2015" is exactly one week. If the second date would be "Wed Sep 23 09:52:36 IRST 2015" the difference would be one week and one hour, which does not match your requirement "precisely calculate the time one week". Or did you mean "the same time on the same weekday in approximately one week"?

Comment: Duh duh du-daaaah, [Rule #9](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Comment: ...*and* [Rule #37](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Comment: @simon You are right, i will use my code, thanks for your comments

Answer (score 14):

Never, ever rely on millisecond arithmetic, there are too many rules and gotchas to make it of any worth (even over a small span of time), instead use a dedicated library, like Java 8's Time API, JodaTime or even `Calendar`

## Java 8

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime then = now.plusDays(7);

System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(then);
```

Which outputs

```
2015-09-16T15:34:14.771
2015-09-23T15:34:14.771
```

## JodaTime

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime then = now.plusDays(7);

System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(then);
```

Which outputs

```
2015-09-16T15:35:19.954
2015-09-23T15:35:19.954
```

## Calendar

When you can't use Java 8 or JodaTime

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
Date then = cal.getTime();

System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(then);
```

Which outputs

```
Wed Sep 16 15:36:39 EST 2015
Wed Sep 23 15:36:39 EST 2015
```

**nb:** The "problem" you seem to be having, isn't a problem at all, but simply the fact that over the period, your time zone seems to have entered/exited day light savings, so `Date` is displaying the time, with it's correct offset

Comment: This code works only if the user happens to be in a time zone, where there is no time zone change between the two dates. For example, adding the line - cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Iran")); - in your "Calendar" example would produce a differnet output. And consequently, the examples would not work for users (e.g. the original poster) who have Iran as their default time zone.

Comment: Taking a given Date and adding 7 days to it should have little effect on the underlying representation of the Date, how the format of the date is represented would come down to local specific requirements, but the underlying millisecond representation would remain the same, because it's base on a single point of time. Besides, my argument isn't about how the formatting of the date value my change, but what are better mechanisms for dat arithmetic

Comment: I agree. However, the result is not any different than just adding the milliseconds as in the OP's example. The problem OP experiences comes from the different time zone representation of the two dates, and cannot be solved by adding the 7 days in a different manner.

Comment: Then their isn't actual a problem (other then the fact they are using a bad approach to achieve it), the fact that there has been a change in daylight savings doesn't change the fact the result is still +7 days in the future, with offset

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println(cal.getTime());

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);

System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is because of the different timezone. [IRDT](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/irdt) is +0430 and [IRST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/irst) is +0330

To overcome this issue you can use the **JodaTime**.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime nextweek = now.plusDays(7);
System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(nextweek);
```

Answer (score 1):

As other said. It would be better to use Calendar or JodaTime library. **But the question is why you were not getting the desired result.** <strike>It was because `currentTimeMillis()` calculates time between "computer time" and coordinated universal time (UTC). Now consider following case.</strike>

```
long DURATION = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
Date now = new Date();
Date nextWeek = new Date(now.getTime() + DURATION);
System.out.println("      now: " + now);
System.out.println("next week: " + nextWeek);
```

here `Date.getTime()` calculate time from 00:00:00 GMT every time and then when converted to string will give time for your local time zone.

**Edit :**
I was wrong. The reason is as [simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76777/simon) said.

> The actual "why" is that IRDT (Iran Daylight Time) ends on September
>   22nd. That's why the first date (September 16th) in the OP's post is
>   displayed as IRDT and the second date (September 23rd) is displayed as
>   IRST. Because IRST (Iran Standard Time) is one hour earlier than IRDT
>   the time displayed is 08:52:36 instead of 09:52:36.

Comment: @Alen could you tell me your TImeZone and locale?

Comment: The actual "why" is that IRDT (Iran Daylight Time) ends on September 22nd. That's why the first date (September 16th) in the OP's post is displayed as IRDT and the second date (September 23rd) is displayed as IRST. Because IRST (Iran Standard Time) is one hour earlier than IRDT the time displayed is 08:52:36 instead of 09:52:36.